# representation problem of rotation transformations given eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, rotations, symmetric-matrices

I've been having issues to solve the following problem.

Prove that all 2 by 2 matrices (over $\mathbb{R}$) with eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda=-1$ can be represented as:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & a \sin \theta \\
\frac{1}{a} \sin \theta &  - \cos \theta 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

or

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cosh \theta & a \sinh \theta \\
-\frac{1}{a} \sinh \theta &  - \cosh \theta 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Also, when a 2 by 2 matrices (over $\mathbb{R}$) with eigenvalues 1 and -1 are symmetric and orthogonal simultaneouly?

The thing is that I cannot wrap it out how to tackle it, is it related to change of basis?

Look, for example the matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0  & 1 \\
1  & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$ it has eigenvalues 1 and -1, it is symmetric and orthogonal but I don't  see clearly how to prove that it can be represented as the previous matrices (or basis). If it were concern with change of coordinates then I'll have to solve a system of equations, at least for the first vector as follows

\begin{align} 
0= c_1 \cos \theta + c_2 a \sin \theta \\
1= c_1 \frac{1}{a} \sin \theta - c_2 \cos \theta\\
\end{align}

But then, what's the meaning of $\mathbf{a}$? (beacuse I doesn't say anything about it). So is it concern with rotations?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The matrix may not be symmetric or orthogonal, take $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 3 \\ -1 & -2\end{pmatrix}$ for example.

Comment: For sure, but then how can be proved that it can be represented as sines and cosines? :/

Comment: It can't be represented by $\cos$ but by $\cosh$ instead.  Di

Answer (score 1):

Just a sketch: We know that the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A$reads 
$$\lambda^2-\operatorname{trace}(A)\lambda+\det(A),$$
on the other hand 
$$\lambda^2-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)\lambda+\lambda_1\lambda_2.$$

Here the trace of the matrix $A$ vanishes and it's determinant is $-1$ so we may write
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}c&x\\y&-c\end{pmatrix}.$$
Notice that $x=0$ is trivial; we assume $x\neq0$.
I'll consider the case $-1< c<1$, the other case may be treated similarly.

Now if $-1\leq c\leq1$ there exist $\theta$ with $c=\cos(\theta)$. From $-1=\det(A)=-\cos^2(\theta)-xy$ and $\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1$ we conclude $xy=\sin^2(\theta)$ where $\sin(\theta)$ doesn't vanish (Why?). Hence we may let $x=a\sin(\theta)$ and $y=\sin(\theta)/a$.

For the remaining case use that $\cosh^2(\theta)-\sinh^2(\theta)=1$.

Comment: Why is the trace important? $x=0$ is trivial? What do you mean? Hehe

Comment: For trace see my edit, please.  For the case $x=0$ write simply write down such a matrix and meditate some seconds.

Comment: Oh sure you're right! The only thing is that why did you assume the matrix A its diagonalized matrix  \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0\\ 0& \lambda_2\end{bmatrix}  when using the formula and then working with a more general matrix?